# Uncaught (in promise) Error: SsdMobilenetv1

Tags: javascript

estou tentando usar o face-api porem esta aparecendo o seguinte erro: Uncaught (in promise) Error: SsdMobilenetv1 - load model before inference at e.forwardInput (face-api.min.js:1:550901) at e. (face-api.min.js:1:552586) at face-api.min.js:1:1935 at Object.next (face-api.min.js:1:2040) at n (face-api.min.js:1:811)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Detecção Facial</title>

    <script defer src="./face-api.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="./main.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        canvas {
            position: absolute;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" width="720" height="560" muted></video>
</body>
</html>

const constraints = { video: true };
const cam = document.querySelector('#video');

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo);

async function startVideo() {
  try {
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

    cam.srcObject = stream;
    cam.onloadedmetadata = e => {
      cam.play();
    };

    // Depois que a webcam estiver ativa, carregue as descrições dos rostos
    const labeledFaceDescriptors = await getLabeledFaceDescriptions();
    const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(labeledFaceDescriptors);

    const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(cam);
    document.body.append(canvas);

    const displaySize = { width: cam.width, height: cam.height };
    faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);

    setInterval(async () => {
      const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(cam, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
        .withFaceLandmarks()
        .withFaceDescriptors()
        .withFaceExpressions();

      const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);

      canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      const results = resizedDetections.map(d => {
        return faceMatcher.findBestMatch(d.descriptor);
      });

      results.forEach((result, i) => {
        const box = resizedDetections[i].detection.box;
        const drawBox = new faceapi.draw.DrawBox(box, {
          label: result.toString(),
        });
        drawBox.draw(canvas);
      });

      faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
      faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections);
      faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
    }, 100);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function getLabeledFaceDescriptions() {
  const labels = ["Lucelia", "Joao"];
  return Promise.all(
    labels.map(async label => {
      const descriptions = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        const img = await faceapi.fetchImage(`./labels/${label}/${i}.jpg`);
        const detections = await faceapi
          .detectSingleFace(img)
          .withFaceLandmarks()
          .withFaceDescriptor();
        descriptions.push(detections.descriptor);
      }
      return new faceapi.LabeledFaceDescriptors(label, descriptions);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Considerando que [esta pergunta já foi feita antes](/questions/585193/uncaught-in-promise-error-ssdmobilenetv1-load-model-before-inference)  e instruções já foram dadas, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar duplicidade de orientações. Você pode restaurar sua [postagem original](/questions/585193/uncaught-in-promise-error-ssdmobilenetv1-load-model-before-inference) conforme as instruções passadas lá, e ao editar aquela postagem, ela será automaticamente destacada para que a comunidade reavalie via voto se está adequada ao objetivo do site.